# Dataframes' subtraction and assignment gives back NAs

Tags: python, pandas

Let's suppose that I have a dataset (`df_data`) such as the following:

```
Time    Geography                Population
2016    England and Wales        58381200
2017    England and Wales        58744600
2016    Northern Ireland         1862100
2017    Northern Ireland         1870800
2016    Scotland                 5404700
2017    Scotland                 5424800
2016    Wales                    3113200
2017    Wales                    3125200
```

If I do the following:

```
df_nireland = df_data[df_data['Geography']=='Northern Ireland']
df_wales = df_data[df_data['Geography']=='Wales']
df_scotland = df_data[df_data['Geography']=='Scotland']
df_engl_n_wales = df_data[df_data['Geography']=='England and Wales']

df_england = df_engl_n_wales

df_england['Population'] = df_engl_n_wales['Population'] - df_wales['Population']
```

then the `df_england` has NA values at the column `Population`.

How can I fix this?

By the way, I have read relevant posts but exactly worked for me (`.loc`, `.copy` etc).

Comment: You have a mismatch in your indexes. When you subtract `-`, pandas matches the `indexes` of both series. Suppose you do `df_1['col'] - df_2['col']`: If a certain row, with a certain index, is present in `df_1` but not present in `df_2`, that row will appear in the final `df` with a `NaN` value in its place, given both `df_1` and `df_2` have the same length.

Comment: Yes @RafaelC I just realised this too and posted an answer below. Is this the most efficient way to resolve this as I show below?

Comment: Your solution is one way to fix it. When you `reset_index`, you get every index to be the same. However, if `index` is not important then, you might just not reset index, and subtract only the `values`: i.e.,keeping your code, and doing `df_engl_n_wales['Population'] - df_wales['Population'].values`

Comment: @RafaelC, yes this makes sense too even though I think that I am not interested in the initial indices and also I prefer to have them all reset to avoid any other such issues in the future.

Comment: I think if there is no guarantee that years are the same and in the same order for each geography, it is probably better to set year as an index. This would ensure that we're subtracting 2017 from 2017 etc. when you do `df_engl_n_wales['Population'] - df_wales['Population']`

Comment: I agree. By resenting the index, or using `.values`, you are basically relying on the ordering of the data frame.I wouldn't rely on the order of the data frame: that's why indexes exist !

Comment: @RafaelC, yes good point even though in my case the years and their orders is the same but in principle what you are suggesting is the way to go. By the way, I thought that when we do df_1['col'] - df_2['col'] pandas simply matches the rows in the order they are in the dataframe without requiring and indices. –

Comment: Nope!!! pandas doesn't match the rows, it matches the indexes ! Be careful with that.

Comment: @RafaelC, cool thanks.

Comment: If you want a simple test, just do `pd.Series([1,2,3,4], index=[10,20,30,40]) - pd.Series([1,2,3,4])` and see what happens. Now try `pd.Series([1,2,3,4], index=[10,20,30,40]) - pd.Series([1,2,3,4]).values`. Now, even, try to use `sub` with `fill_value` to learn a new way that might be handy in the future ;) `pd.Series([1,2,3,4], index=[10,20,30,40]).sub(pd.Series([1,2,3,4]), fill_value=0)`

Comment: @RafaelC, just a quick question. Still how do you know that the `df_engl_n_wales['Population'] - df_wales['Population'].values` assigns the values to the right rows? You are also here relying on the fact that the years and value must be in the same order since you are simply using `df_wales['Population'].values`. Am I missing something?

Comment: @PoeteMaudit definitely ! It relies on the order. I just gave you this option because it is better than reseting every index, but the output should be the same.

Comment: @RafaelC, yes the output is the same but my point is that again you are relying on he order so even this solution is not necessarily better than other in terms of that.

Comment: @PoeteMaudit Yep, My point was not to correct your solution, but rather give you a simpler way to get to the same output without modifying *every data frame* on the way

Comment: @RafaelC, ok yes in this sense it is better but I thought that you were suggesting that it was better also because it does not rely on the order etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had simply to do the following:

```
df_nireland = df_data[df_data['Geography']=='Northern Ireland'].reset_index(drop=True)
df_wales = df_data[df_data['Geography']=='Wales'].reset_index(drop=True)
df_scotland = df_data[df_data['Geography']=='Scotland'].reset_index(drop=True)
df_engl_n_wales = df_data[df_data['Geography']=='England and Wales'].reset_index(drop=True)

df_england = df_engl_n_wales

df_england['Population'] = df_engl_n_wales['Population'] - df_wales['Population']
```

or better way in principle since you are retaining the indices of the initial dataframe is the following:

```
df_nireland = df_data[df_data['Geography']=='Northern Ireland']
df_wales = df_data[df_data['Geography']=='Wales']
df_scotland = df_data[df_data['Geography']=='Scotland']
df_engl_n_wales = df_data[df_data['Geography']=='England and Wales']

df_england = df_engl_n_wales

df_england['Population'] = df_engl_n_wales['Population'] - df_wales['Population'].values
```

Answer (score 0):

This is really an organization problem. If you `pivot` then you can do the subtractions easily, and ensure alignment on `Time`

```
df_pop = df.pivot(index='Time', columns='Geography', values='Population')
df_pop['England'] = df_pop['England and Wales'] - df_pop['Wales']
```

#### Output `df_pop`:

```
Geography  England and Wales  Northern Ireland  Scotland    Wales   England
Time                                                                       
2016                58381200           1862100   5404700  3113200  55268000
2017                58744600           1870800   5424800  3125200  55619400
```

---

If you need to get back to your original format, then you can do:

```
df_pop.stack().to_frame('Population').reset_index()

#   Time          Geography  Population
#0  2016  England and Wales    58381200
#1  2016   Northern Ireland     1862100
#2  2016           Scotland     5404700
#3  2016              Wales     3113200
#4  2016            England    55268000
#5  2017  England and Wales    58744600
#6  2017   Northern Ireland     1870800
#7  2017           Scotland     5424800
#8  2017              Wales     3125200
#9  2017            England    55619400
```